# Disable Scanner and Camera Wizard for all devices through registry update - Windows XP

Tags: windows, camera, windows-xp, wizard, wia

Is there a known way to completely disable the Windows Scanner and Camera Wizard through a registry update? Instead of disabling it per device through the GUI, I would like to be able to disable it completely, so it doesn't come up for any devices. I tried disabling the Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) service, but this prevents Windows from seeing the camera at all.

Adding the following entry to the registry **after** the camera is plugged in the first time will fix the issue, we need to disable it *before* the camera is plugged in for the first time though.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{6BDD1FC6-810F-11D0-BEC7-     08002BE2092F}\0000\Events\Connected]
@="Digital camera connected"
"GUID"="{A28BBADE-64B6-11d2-A231-00C04FA31809}"
"LaunchApplications"="*"
"DefaultHandler"="{E0372B7D-E115-4525-BC55-B629E68C745A}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{6BDD1FC6-810F-11D0-BEC7-08002BE2092F}\0000\Events\Connected\{E0372B7D-E115-4525-BC55-B629E68C745A}]
"Name"="internal"
"Desc"="internal handler"
"Icon"="wiashext.dll, -101"
```

One the above is ran against a computer that has had the camera plugged into it already, the wizard no longer opens. If you run this registry fix before plugging the camera in for the first time, the camera will create a new registry key and the Wizard will still open.

Answer (score 0):

Rename wiaacmgr.exe to wiaacmgr_old.exe
Create dummy file wiaacmgr.exe
You can use this program:

```
// dummy.c --  rename the exe to %WINDIR%/system32/wiaacmgr.exe
int __stdcall WinMain(void*a, void*b, void*v, int d) {}
```

You should get pure zen silence
I tested it with iPhone.
Maybe someone can suggest existing exe from windows folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the services and disabled the Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) service.